# ByPass credential prompting on drive map - windows server 2k3

Tags: windows-server-2003, mappeddrive, credentials

I have 2 windows server 2k3 machines - server A and server B, Server A is on the company domain, and Server B is not.  I have a need to bypass the credential prompting that happens every time I map a drive from Server B to Server A.  The reason i need to do this is that I'm running a program called SourceAnywhere on Server A that points to a VSS database on Server B.  (SourceAnywhere solves the slowness issues that VSS http access has).  While I can configure SourceAnywhere to point to this VSS database (after mapping drive and getting access), I cannot connect to the VSS database from my development machine - i get an error saying I can access database alias..  I'm thinking this might have to do with Server B prompting me for credentials from Server A since it isn't on the domain.  Is there anyway to store these credentials?  or do i need to get Server B added to the domain?

Answer (score 2):

The key would be to map a persistent drive to the server in the other domain (check reconnect at logon).  Do not enter your credentials on the drive mapping page though, instead hit connect/OK and wait for Windows to prompt you.  Then enter your username and password and click the box to save them.

Any future connection to that server during your logon session will utilize the secure channel that was setup in the drive mapping.  Because you set the drive mapping to persistent and saved the username and password, you should not be prompted in the future.